# Google API get refrest token: Uncaught ReferenceError: offline is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to get refresh token once user authorize with google. 
So that user don't have to authorize again. 
I studied documentation from Google, and I come to know I have to put access type offline.

Now , I trying with following javascript code :

```
 var cid = 'XXXXX';
 var apik = 'XXXX';
 var scopes = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';


function authorizeWithGoogle() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apik); 
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: cid, scope: scopes, immediate: false,     accesstype: offline }, handleAuthResult);}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(authResult));
        $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token=" + authResult.access_token + "&max-results=11700&v=3.0",
        handleGoogleContacts);
    }
}
```

HTML Code is :

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Google" onclick="authorizeWithGoogle()"/>

 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```

It is giving me following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: offline is not defined

Can anybody help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accesstype: offline` <-- that is looking for a variable offline, not a string. Wrap it in quotes.

`accesstype: "offline"`

Next issue is the fact you are using a submit button, but you do not cancel the form submission so the page is going to submit.

```
onclick="authorizeWithGoogle(); return false"
```

There are better ways to cancel it, but that will work fine with inline events.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Now, I am getting result in following format, I am not getting refresh token {"state":"","access_token":"","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3600","scope":"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts","client_id":"","response_type":"token","issued_at":"1429740898","expires_at":"1429744498","status":{"google_logged_in":false,"signed_in":true,"method":"PROMPT"}}